# File I/O, fgets() and strtok() function in C

Tags: c

Inside the file.txt :

```
FIRST TYPEONE  
FIRST TYPETWO  
FIRST TYPETHREE  
SEC TYPETHREE  
FIRST TYPETWO  
FIRST TYPEONE  
SEC TYPETWO  
FIRST TYPETHREE  
FIRST TYPEONE
```

When I execute the code, all "function()" doesn't work. First token (token#1) takes "FIRST", printf#1 print "FIRST" and enters the if condition. So far, it's okay. Token that is inside the if condition takes "TYPEONE" and printf#2 prints "TYPEONE". I think token keeps "TYPEONE" currently. But when i use strcmp and compare token and "TYPEONE" it doesn't enter this condition(condition#1) and so 
function() that is inside the condition#1 doesn't work and printf function doesn't print "type1" to screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 200

int main()
{   
    char lineSize[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    char *token;
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    while (i< 9)
    {
        fgets(lineSize, MAX_LINE_SIZE, f); 
        token = strtok(lineSize, " "); //token#1

        printf("%s\n", token); //printf#1

        if( strcmp(token, "FIRST") == 0 )
        {   
            token = strtok(NULL , " "); //token#2

            printf("%s\n\n", token); //printf#2


            if( strcmp(token, "TYPETWO") == 0 )
                {function(); printf("type2\n");
                }
            else if( strcmp(token, "TYPETHREE") == 0 )
                {function(); printf("type3\n");
                }
            else if( strcmp(token, "TYPEONE") == 0 ) //condition#1
                {function(); printf("type1\n");
                }
        }

        else if( (strcmp(token, "SEC")) == 0  ) 
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");

            if( (strcmp(token, "TYPETWO")) == 0 )
                {
                    function();
                    printf("type2\n");
                }

            else if( (strcmp(token, "TYPETHREE")) == 0 )
                {
                    function();
                    pritf("type3\n");
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program contains typographical errors and doesn't even compile.  Did you copy-and-paste it from your C coding environment, or did you retype it here?  If you retyped it, it probably contains other slight differences from the code you're actually running, differences which may make it impossible for us to accurately debug.

Comment: In fact, when I correct the two obvious errors (add declaration `int i = 0;`, change `pritf` to `printf`), the code seems to work fine.  What's the problem you're having with it, again?

Comment: (for a start) You are not recognising newlines: `token = strtok(lineSize, " ");`  -->> `token = strtok(lineSize, " \t\n"); `

Comment: should I assume variable `i` is defined somewhere? Is it initialized to a correct value?  your program doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know what do you pretend with your sample, but it's ill formed.  I've just made the minimum set of tests to the results of the functions you call to be able to compile and run the sample program you post.  But anyway, I don't exactly see what do you want with it.  PLEASE, post a complete and verifiable example of code (your `i` variable was neither defined, nor initialised anywhere, no `function()` definition anywhere, and no function return value check for errors anywhere also)
What do you mean with `function()` does not work... no definition of function `function()` anywhere.  How can we diagnose what happens with `function()` if you don't post it?

Next is the set of modifications you need to your program (in the form of a patch file, `diff -u`) to make it runnable, but next time, please, check your code for being at least runnable to ask something here (the error messages where clear enough to be able to do it by yourself)

```
--- pru.c.orig  2018-03-12 09:03:54.000000000 +0200
+++ pru.c   2018-03-12 09:17:11.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,23 +1,41 @@
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
+#include <errno.h>
+
 #define MAX_LINE_SIZE 200

+void function()
+{
+    printf("in function();\n");
+}
+
 int main()
 {   
     char lineSize[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
     char *token;
     FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
+    int i = 0;
+
+    if (!f) { /* CHECK FOR ERRORS */
+        fprintf(stderr,
+                "ERROR: fopen: file.txt: %s\n",
+                strerror(errno));
+        exit(1);
+    }
+
     while (i< 9)
     {
         fgets(lineSize, MAX_LINE_SIZE, f); 
         token = strtok(lineSize, " "); //token#1
+        if (!token) break; /* CHECK FOR ERRORS */

         printf("%s\n", token); //printf#1

         if( strcmp(token, "FIRST") == 0 )
         {   
             token = strtok(NULL , " "); //token#2
+            if (!token) break; /* CHECK FOR ERRORS */

             printf("%s\n\n", token); //printf#2

@@ -36,6 +54,7 @@
         else if( (strcmp(token, "SEC")) == 0  ) 
         {
             token = strtok(NULL, " ");
+            if (!token) break; /* CHECK FOR ERRORS */

             if( (strcmp(token, "TYPETWO")) == 0 )
                 {
@@ -46,9 +65,13 @@
             else if( (strcmp(token, "TYPETHREE")) == 0 )
                 {
                     function();
-                    pritf("type3\n");
+                    printf("type3\n");
                 }

         }
+        i++;
     }
+    if (i < 9) /* CHECK FOR ERRORS */
+        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: less than 9 lines of input (%d).\n", i+1);
+    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The code without the unified diff formatting is generally more helpful.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to bolden the points where the code needs refactoring and also trying not to do all the work for the student.  It's clear that what is being asked is some kind of homework.  The `diff` output will be fine to make him learn at least how to edit his own file and what each modification mean.  And also will help him to understand a `diff(1)` output.  And solution is complete this way.

Comment: You would be surprised how many time the OP wouldn't know whether that was unified diff or C-syntax -- best to keep it stupid simple... (I knew what you meant by it, but it is just a very non-standard way of emphasizing your changes)

Comment: Nope, i don't get surprised with anything a student can demand from me.  I'm very used to answer demands for homework problems, and I know what I'm doing, sure! :)

Comment: I know it's not standard.... but it's automatic way, and indeed is something that he, if continues studying will have to understand, sooner or later.  I don't thinkg I should move to a simpler output... I think it is the student who has to do some work on behalf of himself.  StackOverflow's objectives where not to solve students homework, and I want to emphasize this.